# Microsoft onedrive: Create folder using API key without login

Tags: c#, onedrive

I am able to create folders and files in onedrive using `Graph API`. However first time I have to login to Microsoft account. Following is the link where I need to login:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code+id_token&scope={scope}&state={state}&nonce={nonce}&x-client-SKU={x-client-SKU}&x-client-ver={x-client-ver}
```

I wish to implement all these server sides. How could I get it done without login to Microsoft account? IF it is possible using some console code, then I think it could be done.

Comment: You can't. if you could do that, anyone could create folders in your account, since the API key is not guaranteed to be secret. You probably want to read this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-service

Comment: I agree with your point. However I have written logic to create folder in my OneDrive on a particular event. I can do that by mapping my OneDrive on server and then creating folder manually in mapped location, but that will create all the files and folders in my server's storage.

Comment: Read the link I gave you. It will show you how to connect using the API without having a manual log in. Nothing to do with mapping the OneDrive onto your server.

Comment: Thanks ADyson, I followed the provided link. I was able to generate token using Postman. Initially I authorized the request and got code from Microsoft. Then I generated access_token and refresh_token. Then I saved refresh token to generate new token. Then I made POST request to [link](https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token) along with refresh_token. That gave me new access token and refresh token. I used this access token to create folder by making post request to [link](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children) with folder name. Thanks again.

Comment: glad you found a way. You should post it as an Answer, not just a comment. You are allowed to answer your own question! And then people can upvote your solution if they find it useful :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I performed following steps to create a console application to create folder in OneDrive:

### 1. Create Microsoft app:

1. Log into https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/
2. Create a new app
3. Enter some app name
4. Generate a new password an Application Secretes section
5. Add Platform in Platforms section.
6. Added a Web platform
7. Provide some redirect Url. This would be required, you may enter any localhost url also. I entered http://localhost:100/
8. Add following Delegate Permissions in Microsoft Graph Permissions section
9. Files.ReadWriteAll, Directory.ReadWriteAll, offline_access (offline access is very important permission, without this permission you will not be able to generate access token automatically)
10. Make sure LiveSDKSupport checkbox is checked in Advanced Options.

### 2. Generate CODE value for access token

1. Update following url with your app id (step 1.b) and redirect url (step 1.g).
2. https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id={client_id}&scope=User.Read User.ReadWrite User.ReadBasic.All Mail.Send Calendars.ReadWrite Mail.ReadWrite Files.ReadWrite offline_access&response_type=code&redirect_uri={redirect_url}
3. Paste url in browser address bar and make a get request(hit enter)
4. Login to your one drive account
5. Accept the user agreement
6. Code redirect url and get code query string from redirect url

### 3. Generate access token and refresh token from code value

1. Open Postman
2. Make a post request with following settings:
   endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token

   - Headers > Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - Body >
   - client_id: your client/app id from step 1
   - redirect_uri: your redirect url from step 1
   - client_secret: your client secret (app password generated in step 1)
   - code: code generated in step 2
   - grant_type: authorization_code
3. This will return a json with some values. Copy access_token and refresh_token from response. Access token can be used to create folder in one drive. However that will be valid from some time. To get new token we will required to generate new token using refresh token. Hence store refresh token in configuration file along with client id client secret and redirect url.

### 4. Generate access token from code:

1. This can be done from Postman as well as from code using simple post request with following parameters:

   - Endpoint: https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
   - Method: Post
   - Content Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - Data: "client_id={client_id}&redirect_uri={redirect_url}&client_secret={client_secret}&grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token={refresh_token}"
2. This will return access token in response. Use that access token to create folder in one drive.

### 5. Create folder in OneDrive:

1. Make a post request to create folder:

   - Endpoint: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/children
   - Authorization: "Bearer {access_token generated in step 4}"
   - ContentType: application/json
   - Post Data: new { name = FolderName, folder = new { childCount = 0 } };